# how do i make multiple fs requests in libuv?

Tags: c, io, libuv

I've been reading the docs and tried looking through the source code of projects using libuv and it's only made me more confused as to how to even setup two basic requests :((

```
uv_fs_open(uv_loop, &open_req, path1, O_RDONLY, 0, on_open);
uv_fs_open(uv_loop, &open_req, path2, O_RDONLY, 0, on_open);
```

where and how exactly am i supposed to define and cleanup `open_req` (and others... read_req etc)
and am i using the `on_open` function correctly here?

I've tried the examples from the docs and they didn't really help me understand.
A example of how to open two or more text files and print them using libuv would be a lot of help.

Comment: The official guide is [here](https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/filesystem.html#reading-writing-files), but the first line of each snippet is missing! You can see the missing lines --and in fact the entire program-- [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/docs/code/uvcat/main.c)

Comment: @ikegami i used that exact program, it works but it only opens one file, my question is how to open multiple files, read them, close them.

Comment: Use a different var for the second arg of each call. It holds request and response information for that call, so you can't reuse it (or free it) until the call completes. Same for the other calls.